# Как сделать небольшой опросник на js?

Tags: javascript

Не могу до ума довести опросник.

```js
var btnResutl = document.getElementById('btnResutl'),
  resultFild = document.getElementById('resultFild'),
  firstAnswer = [2, 6, 9, 2],
  secondAnswer = [5, 8, 1, 7],
  thirdAnswer = [6, 1, 5, 3],
  fourAnswer = [4, 2, 7, 3],
  arr = [],
  arr2 = [];

var inputFild = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
btnResutl.addEventListener('click', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < inputFild.length; i++) {
    if (inputFild[i].checked) {
      var sum = arr.push(firstAnswer[i] + secondAnswer[i])
      var sumTwo = arr2.push(thirdAnswer[i] + fourAnswer[i])
    }
    resultFild.innerHTML = sum + ' баллов'
  }
})
```

```html
<h4>Your test</h4>
<h3>Try yourself</h3>
<div class="question">
  <p>Do you have..</p>
  <input type="radio" name="r1" id="Answer"><label>Home</label>
  <input type="radio" name="r1" id="Answer"><label>Sity</label>
  <input type="radio" name="r1" id="Answer"><label>Advanture</label>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <p>Do you have..</p>
  <input type="radio" name="r2" id="Answer"><label>Home</label>
  <input type="radio" name="r2" id="Answer"><label>Sity</label>
  <input type="radio" name="r2" id="Answer"><label>Advanture</label>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <p>Do you have..</p>
  <input type="radio" name="r3" id="Answer"><label>Home</label>
  <input type="radio" name="r3" id="Answer"><label>Sity</label>
  <input type="radio" name="r3" id="Answer"><label>Advanture</label>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <p>Do you have..</p>
  <input type="radio" name="r4" id="Answer"><label>Home</label>
  <input type="radio" name="r4" id="Answer"><label>Sity</label>
  <input type="radio" name="r4" id="Answer"><label>Advanture</label>
</div>
<button id="btnResutl">Result</button>
<div id="resultFild"></div>
```

Результатом должно быть одно число в зависимости от выбранных чекбоксов.
У меня проблема с прибавление этих массивов. Подскажите как с ними в данном случае работать?

Comment: Не может быть на странице одно `ID` у разных элементов  `id="Answer"` замени на `class`

Comment: А в чем конкретно "проблема с прибавление этих массивов"?

Comment: @ Andy, проблема в том, что не складываются числа. я не правильно делаю с ними операцию прибавления. если запустить код, все станет понятно.

Comment: В место `про тухлые помидоры`, лучше подробнее описать проблему...  в чем именно проблема и и каков желаемый результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как один из вариантов, хранить "стоимость" вопроса в value:

```js
var btnResutl = document.getElementById('btnResutl');
var resultFild = document.getElementById('resultFild');


var inputFild = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
btnResutl.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0, l = inputFild.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (inputFild[i].checked){
      sum += parseInt(inputFild[i].value);
    }
    resultFild.innerHTML = sum + ' баллов'; 
  }
});
```

```html
<h4>Your test</h4>
  <h3>Try yourself</h3>
  <div class="question">
    <p>Do you have..</p>
    <input type="radio" name="r1" class="Answer" value="2"><label>Home</label>
    <input type="radio" name="r1" class="Answer" value="6"><label>Sity</label>
    <input type="radio" name="r1" class="Answer" value="9"><label>Advanture</label>
  </div>

  <div class="question">
    <p>Do you have..</p>
    <input type="radio" name="r2" class="Answer" value="5"><label>Home</label>
    <input type="radio" name="r2" class="Answer" value="8"><label>Sity</label>
    <input type="radio" name="r2" class="Answer" value="1"><label>Advanture</label>
  </div>

  <div class="question">
    <p>Do you have..</p>
    <input type="radio" name="r3" class="Answer" value="6"><label>Home</label>
    <input type="radio" name="r3" class="Answer" value="1"><label>Sity</label>
    <input type="radio" name="r3" class="Answer" value="5"><label>Advanture</label>
  </div>

  <div class="question">
    <p>Do you have..</p>
    <input type="radio" name="r4" class="Answer" value="4"><label>Home</label>
    <input type="radio" name="r4" class="Answer" value="2"><label>Sity</label>
    <input type="radio" name="r4" class="Answer" value="7"><label>Advanture</label>
  </div>
  <button id="btnResutl">Result</button>
  <div id="resultFild"></div>
```